# How to handle errors inside didFailProvisionalNavigation properly?

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I have a viewController with a wkwebview inside it that acts as a custom webBrowser inside my app. I am getting the following errors when i try to access certain urls:

- Sometimes a url will throw -1008 (resource unavailable) error when i try to open it the first time (after launching the app), successive tries work fine though.
- While navigation a website, clicking on a link leads to -999 (operation could not be completed) error, even though i click on a link inside the website only after it had loaded. So don't know how the operation did not complete. Moreover, the link clicked on website loads just fine.

I couldn't find much on these errors, is there a way to handle all of the possible ones robustly.

A similar question was asked before but didn't get a response: [How do I properly implement didFailProvisionalNavigation with WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45131361/how-do-i-properly-implement-didfailprovisionalnavigation-with-wkwebview)